# Translate/Replace Multiple Letters With Python

Tags: python, translate

I am working on a very basic translation program. Currently it can only deal with one letter in a phrase. For example if I were to input "test" it would blurt out "yesy" because it changes "t" to "y". Here's the code I use to do that:

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "t":
            translation = translation + "y"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation




print(translate(input("Enter word: ")))
```

Is it possible to add another letter to be translated. So for example "e" to "a" on top of "t" to "y". so that it would spit out "yasy".

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)?

Comment: Yes, it's very much possible. Though I'm not sure that's what you are looking for...?

Comment: How about `my_str.replace(...).replace(...)` ?

Comment: Yes, and there are many examples on line of how to do this, given various levels of change.  Please research before posting here.  Among other things, read about the `replace` and `translate` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a much easier way using `str.replace`: `'test'.replace('t','y').replace('e','a')`

However, if you're looking to replace more and more letters `str.translate` would be more efficient:

```
from string import maketrans

trans_from = "te"
trans_to = "ya"
trans_model = maketrans(trans_from, trans_to)

'test'.translate(trans_model)
```

Or, if you want to keep your code, you can use `elif`:

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "t":
            translation = translation + "y"
        elif letter in "e":
            translation = translation + "a"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter word: ")))
```

Comment: Do you mind indenting the ´elif´ part of the code properly. I can't seem to get it to work when I manually indent it. When I input "test" it comes out with "yayt".

Comment: @Mihkel Indented properly now

Comment: Works perfectly, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
en-gb = {'t':'y', add more here}
def translate(phrase): 
    translation = str()
    for char in phrase:
        translation = translation +   en-gb[char]
    return translation
```